# newline character in c# string

Tags: c#, string, newline

I have some html code in a C# string. If I look with the Text Visualizer of Visual Studio I can see it has numerous newlines in it. However, after i apply this code

```
string modifiedString = originalString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

and then I look with the Text Visualizer at modifiedString I can see it doesn't have anymore newlines except for 3 places. Are there any other character types than resemble newline and I am missing?

Comment: You can check for the char values at specific places, since you mention it is only 3. They may show up as new lines in your text visualizer but not really be new lines.

Comment: NewLine is typically two characters, a carriage return and a line feed.  The text visualizer may show a newline if you just have one of those and not the other.

Comment: NewLine is `\r\n` in `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They might be just a `\r` or a `\n`.  I just checked and the text visualizer in VS 2010 displays both as newlines as well as `\r\n`.

This string

```
string test = "blah\r\nblah\rblah\nblah";
```

Shows up as

```
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

in the text visualizer.

So you could try

```
string modifiedString = originalString
    .Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")
    .Replace("\r", "<br />")
    .Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I did

Answer (score 4):

A great way of handling this is with regular expressions.

```
string modifiedString = Regex.Replace(originalString, @"(\r\n)|\n|\r", "<br/>");
```

This will replace any of the 3 legal types of newline with the html tag.